# Delphi with iOS vs iPAD - UI does not update

Tags: ios, delphi, ipad, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Using Delphi 10.4.1

Buttons, when set to Invisible, will hide in iOS. However, the same buttons will not hide in iPadOS 14.4.

Similarly, the text on a `TLabel` will not refresh automatically when updated.

However, when I click the iPad button (iPad Air), and re-show the iPad app, all
the changes that were supposed to be made show up!

I've tried `TControl.Repaint()` and even the inefficient `Application.ProcessMessages()`. Both do not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: A [mcve] would help

Comment: @DaveNottage was about to work on an example, then found the solution as below.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for taking time to edit the question.  Still trying to get used to formatting certain keywords.

Answer (score 2):

After final testing on a simple project, I concluded that:

- this issue does not exist in a simple project

If I'm able to replicate this issue again in a simple project, I'll update again.

- however, if you experience this in a bigger complex project
  instead of placing the controls on a TToolbar, it may cause this problem of not updating the controls (whether setting the text or hiding it). My solutino is: do not use TToolbar if deploying to iPad. iPhone works fine.

Note this happens on iPad but not iOS for some strange reason.

Comment: After further testing with a simple example, it's in my bigger project that this happens. :( for a project with simple Toolbar etc, it does not happen.  Shall I remove my answer?

Comment: I'd rather you edit (or remove, if it's a mistake) the answer once you find out what the problem is :-)

Comment: Noted, I've updated as per actual experience.